# Using multiple files in Marmalade SDK

Tags: c++, import, marmalade

The title is pretty self explanitory: I'm trying to run a process outside of main.cpp using loadfile.cpp and loadfile.h to handle loading and displaying an image. However, Marmalade keeps throwing build errors when I do this.

At a top level, I am looking for a process that will run in main.cpp, make a call to loadfile.cpp and display an image with the code in loadfile.cpp. Ideally:

in main.cpp:

```
main()
{
    //initialize and setup Marmalade stuff
    Img* myImg; //create an image object

    while (!s3eDeviceCheckQuitRequest()) {
        //More Marmalade stuff
        myImg->display(); //display said image
    }

    delete myImg;
    return 0;
}
```

in loadfile.cpp:

```
#include "loadfile.h"
Img* myImg; //image object

void Img::displayImg()
//display image
```

and in loadfile.h:

```
#if !defined(_LOADFILE_H)
#define _LOADFILE_H

class File
{
public:
    void displayFile();
};

extern Img* myImg;

#endif //_LOADFILE_H
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong or write a brief script showing me it? Thanks very much!

P.S. I wrote this following the Stage 2 Marmalade looking at what they do with the input.cpp/.h files and Input class. I have the full code available if that would be of help!

Comment: Did you figure this out? If not, what error messages are you getting on build?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention all of your source files in the mkb, before you can use them in your project. Look for the mkb's source section to add the files. Once done, reload the mkb to find the newly added file in your project automatically.

Comment: Yep, and you can also simply put in your mkb under [Headers] '`*.h" and under [Sources] "*.cpp", and it will build with any such files in your project directory.